# Why do I need to write JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, nunjucks

I'm writing a Node.js web application which is using Express as framework and Nunjucks as template engine.

One part of the application is to send form data as email. A Nunjucks template with the form data within is compiled during the process, which then is send to the email server.

The form data is a JSON object (`req.body`), but for some strange reason, I need to submit the form data like this:

```
const renderer = nunjucks.configure('/path/to/template');

renderer.render('template.html', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)));
```

Simply writing `renderer.render('template.html', req.body);` isn't working, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: ctx.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at Obj.extend.init (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:338:20)
    at new new_cls (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\object.js:46:28)
    at Obj.extend.render (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:473:23)
    at D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:311:35
    at createTemplate (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:234:25)
    at handle (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:249:25)
    at D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:263:21
    at next (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:207:13)
    at Object.exports.asyncIter (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:214:5)
    at Obj.extend.getTemplate (D:\Projects\vcs.vitra.com\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:242:17)
```

Does somebody has an idea why I need to stringify and parse the form data before it works in Nunjucks? Doesn't seem to make any sense?

**Edit**

Here is the entire function for better explanation:

*Function*

```
function sender(data, callback) {
  const config = require('./config'),
        renderer = nunjucks.configure(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'mail-templates')),
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport((smtpTransport(config.smtp)));

  transporter.sendMail({
    from: `${data.name} <${data.email}>`,
    replyTo: data.email,
    to: config.email.receiver,
    subject: config.email.subject,
    html: renderer.render(`${data.origin}.html`, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))),
  }, callback);
}
```

*Function call*

```
sender(req.body, (message, err) => {
  res.json({ message: message, errors: err });
});
```

*req.body aka data*

```
{ contacttype: 'E-Mail',
  software: '',
  text: 'Test',
  email: '',
  name: '',
  origin: 'contact' }
```

Comment: `renderer.render('template.html, req.body);` is missing an apostrophe - too small an edit for me to make.

Comment: Besides @DanielShillcock (great catch) comment, you use `JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(...))` to pass a COPY of the object and not the object itself. Imagine that you pass this as a parameter to a procedure and, for whatever reason, you want to make a local change to the contents of the JSON. Without the `parse...stringify...`, the change within the procedure will also affect the source (original) object.

Comment: I created a basic express app and I didn't get any errors. Could you please provide your project code?

Comment: @DanielShillcock Yeah thanks for that, edited it. This apostrophe is not missing in the real project file, I just changed it slightly for this thread.

@FDavidov Thanks for pointing that out, wasn't aware of that. Does this mean I could assign the `req.body` to a new variable and it would work?

Comment: @AndreasRemdt Pass req.body  directly - without copying it -  and never manipulate the data in template

Comment: @JanOsch I do pass the req.body directly, see my edit above. Nothing is manipulated in the tempalte, just printed out with {{ name }}

Comment: @AndreasRemdt `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` is an ugly hack to create a real copy of your data.

Comment: @JanOsch A I see. But when I try to pass the data directly (as written in my initial post) I get the attached error message. So what's the issue on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change code to

```
function sender(data, callback) {
    const config = require('./config'),
        renderer = nunjucks.configure(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'mail-templates')),
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport((smtpTransport(config.smtp)));

    renderer.render(`${data.origin}.html`, data, function(err, html){
        if (err)
            return callback(err);

        transporter.sendMail({
            from: `${data.name} <${data.email}>`,
            replyTo: data.email,
            to: config.email.receiver,
            subject: config.email.subject,
            html: html
            }, callback
        );
    }); 
}
```

To create copy/mix of objects use `Object.assign`

```
let copy = Object.assign({}, src1, src2);
```